# Mongodb simple query

Tags: mongodb

Mongodb query question:

```
parent = {
    "_id": ObjectId("1"),
    "children": [ObjectId("11"), ObjectId("12"), ObjectId("13")]
}
```

I want to return the whole parent document if given id matches any in the children array.

```
> db.parent.find({"children": ObjectId("11")})
```

does not return anything

TIA,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

You need to first `get` your `db` this allows node to know what `db` you're talking about. I do this with a simple `_db = db.get('parent')`.
Now you can try and search the db with your `ObjectId`. With `ObjectId` I believe that you can just search `11` since it is just a `String`. If

```
_db = db.get('parent')

_db.find({'children': '11'}, function(err, doc){
    if(!err){
        ...
        Docs will return the whole query
    }else{
        ...
    }
}
```

If just searching for `11` does not work then try using `ObjectId`.

Now when I tried to add `ObjectId` to my `Mongotron` db it returned back with `Error : Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters at new ObjectID`. Are you sure your data is in the `db`?

Comment: I'm positive the id is in the children collection. Also, not looking for node code, just using the mongo command line, right now.

Comment: Have you tried `db.parent.find({'children': '11'})`?

Comment: Sorry, figured out my problem, children is an array inside another collection. So the following worked:

Comment: db.parent.find({"children.grand_children": ObjectId("11")})

Comment: I had to use ObjectId as the string "11" did not work.